# Very strange CSS formatting with React app, major overlapping. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm not even sure how to link to show the problem since webpack and React combine all the CSS into one thing.

Here is a codepen of what the site shows: https://codepen.io/livebacteria/pen/bJpRxq

Code:

```
    <html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  <style type="text/css">body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
</style><style type="text/css">.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.roomContent {
  width: 85%;
}

.roomId {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  top: 0;
  float: top;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.messageList {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

#sign-in-button {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2%;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}</style><style type="text/css">#room-list {
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #797979;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#rooms {
    background-color: darkgray;
    margin: .2em;
    border: .2em solid black;
    border-radius: .5em;
}

.active {
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}</style><style type="text/css">.message {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.alter {
    background-color: teal;
    color: white;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.username {
    left: 0;
    font-weight: bold
}

.msgContent {
    text-align: justify;
}

.timestamp {
    right: 100%;
}

li {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}</style><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.301d260d2d5d7cc6e354.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.1b967c31a26f143b4c18.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.71fa75690276c3793425.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.bd4f9c2dd0d0d73a5767.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.674bf126f112209cc501.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.d51f6dd5d844ba3b041f.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.3b7da7fe7854caba082b.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.83cd193b84cfa377dad0.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.2a3407b574c86757e486.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.593394f8893e7c304918.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.ca86c32b9f61b8f0bb0b.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.8bbf712997dd0b0cc98c.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.8dc8d68395e79c2c6dbd.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.8f1d3411148d4555e4db.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.03f056389193af93776c.hot-update.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" src="/main.9cac50b16b883a71fef4.hot-update.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"><div class="App"><div class="roomListInfo"><div id="room-list"><section id="informationalHeader"><div><h1>Bloc Chat</h1></div></section><section id="rooms"><div><div class="active">room_1</div><div class="">room_2</div><div class="">room_3</div><div class="">Additional Information</div><div class=""></div><div class="">Mentor chat</div><div class="">retest</div><div class=""></div></div></section><section id="createRooms"><div><form><input type="text" id="nameEntry" value=""><input type="submit" disabled="" value="Create Room"></form></div></section></div></div><div class="roomContent"><h1 class="roomId">room_1</h1><div class="messageList"><div><div><ul><li class="username">LiveBactera</li><li class="msgContent">Testing</li><li class="timestamp">No Data</li></ul></div></div></div></div><div class="userInfo"><div><div><button>Sign Out</button><p>Tyler Poore</p></div></div></div></div></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/main.937734484660ad27272f.hot-update.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

But, my problem is that I'm trying to build a chat application / website that you know, looks like one. Perhaps like Slack of all things. I'm having major overlapping issues with different components. I want a top header bar to stay stuck to the top, a nav bar on the left side that is stuck as well and, finally, the content should be scrollable.

I don't even know where to start for CSS. I've done loads of tutorials but nothing makes sense. There feels like there is more to CSS than there is in JS. The only code that works to achieve the sidebar look I'd like to have is the position: fixed style in CSS. I've read that this can cause major issues with other /fixed/ elements and sure enough it has.

The more I mess with the CSS the worse it gets, I had to restart almost the whole project because it got so bad.

Comment: It is very difficult to imagine the exact issue based on this description but per the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html, there is nothing too crazy with the css. May be there is a position: absolute on some parent container thats causing major overlaps?

Comment: Sounds like familiarizing yourself with the basics of [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model) would make life easier but ya, you have to know this is pretty much impossible to help with without a way to reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware its incredibly hard to imagine someone else problem. I gave more information :<

Comment: Seems like you have trouble laying out your application rather than having a particular issue. My advice would be too look into css's native flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. Otherwise there are many ui libraries (react compatible) that may assist you, such as semantic-ui (https://react.semantic-ui.com/) or material-ui (https://material-ui.com/)

Comment: Yeah, it would definitely look that way..... It looked pretty good up until I tried to implement the scrollable chat feature...

Flex does work, but there is another set of issues with that, mainly being that everything changes size whenever react re renders a component.

Edit: After looking at that same guide, Ricardo linked for the twentieth time today..  I noticed the container created by default with create-react-app had css properties on it.. I'm gonna mess with them and see what happens.

Comment: Ran into the same issue again here. https://codepen.io/livebacteria/pen/EJKvNq

Was even  following the guide.

Comment: Bump. I've even gone to the length of using an entire template for the pages css, and this is not working in the slightest....... Certain css properties are not altering each other..

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want roomListInfo on the left, and roomContent on the right?

Some quick fixes:

you need them to be side-by-side instead of stacked on top of each other.  You could do this by making them both `display: inline-block`, and make `roomListInfo` have `width: 15%` to match the `width: 85%` on `roomContent`.  It looks like you tried adding it on `room-list` instead, so you should undo that.

Next, to get `roomContent` to cling to the top of the "line" (cause both are now on a line, like a line of text) that both elements now exist on, instead of sitting on the bottom of it, add `vertical-align: top` to it.

Comment: Vertical align.... Where has that been, i learned that months ago :/

Inline-block has overlap issues as well though. In fact, with this I am almost back to where I started today. https://jsfiddle.net/s3ubq4hx/ (ps. codepen is down rn so here is a jsFiddle)

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this problem. CSS can be confusing to start out with but once you get the core concepts down (classes, Id, declarations) then this will become a lot easier.

A good tip is to separate your CSS into it's own file and then load it using

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR_CSS_FILE_NAME.css">
</head>
```

I would definitely start one-by-by with this page. Don't try to do too many things at once and don't get overwhelmed.

Go through each section thoroughly before moving onto the next.

For the sample below I simulated putting the CSS into a different file, I moved it to the CSS Window and removed the Style Tags.

Then I went through and changes some of the HTML and added the appropriate styles based on what I think you are asking for.

This is just one way to solve this problem, it doesn't mean it's the best.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ROaZGo

Comment: Thank you for the help! I do have all my js, css, and in general components and their bits in separate files. Its just that webpack loads them all into the main index.html at runtime.

I may be missing a few core mechanics but this just hasn't been sitting well with me..... Something is off. https://jsfiddle.net/s3ubq4hx/ 

Even after using recommended css from people above there is still strange overlapping happening.., and to top the that off, literally, there is a whole space above my `vertical-align: top`ed information bar.. There is no padding to be seen, no margins. o.o